# Как сменить версию python на ubuntu

Tags: python, ubuntu, pip

Установил ubuntu, как я понял с ней вместе установился питон2.7 в папку /home/user/.local/lib
Я установил питон3.5 после чего через pip скачиваю всякие библиотки себе в частности scipy и она устанавливается в папку питон2.7, а я не использую 2-ю версию питона.

Помогите мне либо удалить питон 2.7, либо приоритезировать 3.5. 
В гуугле не могу найти достаточно информации чтоб решить.

Comment: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-the-anaconda-python-distribution-on-ubuntu-16-04

Comment: @MaxU а при чем тут анаконда?

Comment: по моему твердому убеждению - это лучший дистрибутив (вне зависимости от платформы) для тех кто хочет пользоваться numpy/scipy/pandas/machine-learning и т.д.

Comment: ПРоблема не в том какую использовать библиотеку, я её просто в пример привел, а как сделать так, чтоб библиотке не качались в 2.7 версию питона, а в 3.5

Comment: но мне кажется что-то у меня вышло

Comment: sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/python python /usr/bin/python3.5 1
Я пока еще не понял как, но эта команда мне помогла решить проблему)

Comment: не надо менять "системный" Python - это источник проблем. Установите для локального пользователя (как описано по ссылке) и забудьте о проблемах

Comment: _> с ней вместе установился питон2.7 в папку /home/user/.local/lib_
системный установщик польлзовательские каталоги оставляет пустыми (разве что при первом входе оболочка может скопировать содержимое /etc/skel)

Comment: 1- не трогайте системный Питон (последствия могут быть неочевидными). Это не мешает вам хоть десять версий Питона использовать, если есть желание. К примеру, вы даже другие реализации Питона можете попробовать такие как pypy, jython. Эти вещи никак не связаны¶ 2- у вас [XY-проблема](https://goo.gl/k9KEwA): системный `pip` использует системный же `python`. Чтобы использовать python3, можно pip3 использовать (или `python3 -mpip`), но лучше в virtualenv pip запускать (e.g., `virtualenv -p python3 venv`). Для удобства, можно [virtualenvwrapper поставить](https://virtualenvwrapper.readthedocs.io).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Используйте `pip3` или `python3 -m pip` для запуска pip для Python 3

```
$ pip3 --version
pip 9.0.1 from /home/r033/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages (python 3.5)
$ python3 -m pip --version
pip 9.0.1 from /home/r033/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages (python 3.5)
```

Так же библиотеки можно устанавливать через репозитории Ubuntu, если они там есть.

```
sudo apt install python3-scipy
```

Answer (score 2):

Попробуйте запускать pip так:

```
sudo python3 -m pip
```

P.S. A scipy для python3 в ubuntu можно так поставить:

```
sudo apt-get install python3-scipy
```

Answer (score -4):

Если я Вас правильно понял, то Вам поможет:

```
sudo ln -sf python3 /usr/bin/python
```

Эта команда заменит ссылку на python в `/usr/bin`

После этого, по запуску python будет открываться интерпретатор python3